# SQL SERVER: Allow a user to create/alter/drop tables within own schema only

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently building a solution where multiple small applications run of a single SQL server database each with their own login and default schema. This solution works fine, but I need to ensure security. The applications has a "designer" element to them and I need to grant create/alter/drop table permissions to only the default schema.

I found a few solutions online, but none actually worked for me during testing.

I'm running sql server 12.0 on Azure. I created a user "DemoApp" with it's schema "DemoApp"

Solution 1: Set the user as the owner of the schema works and restricts access to select etc. outside the schema, but users are able to drop/alter tables of other schemas because of the ALTER permission.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::DemoApp to DemoApp;
GRANT CREATE TABLE, ALTER TO DemoApp;
```

Solution 2: Change the owner of the schema to dbo and only allow specific permissions within the schema.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::DemoApp to dbo;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO DemoApp;
GRANT ALTER, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::DemoApp TO DemoApp
```

According to online posts this solution should work, but I still get 
"CREATE TABLE permission denied in database" when trying to create a table under the DemoApp login.

I would like to run multiple applications on a single database securely where each login/user is restricted to its default schema with full control of objects inside it.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

NEVER grant non-admins the ability to create or modify objects in a schema owned by `dbo`. 
It's utterly insecure.

This should work.  You don't grant ALTER at all.  DemoApp is the owner of the schema, and can drop or alter objects in that schema:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::DemoApp to DemoApp;
GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE TO DemoApp;
```

Comment: I still get "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database". For some reason without the ALTER permission creating tables doesn't work GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, ALTER TO DemoApp; allows DemoApp to create tables, but that raises the insecure problem I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: CREATE TABLE doesn’t allow a user to create tables in every schema, only ones they can ALTER or they own.

Answer (score 0):

Grant Alter permission to a schema like below for this to work

```
      GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::<<SCHEMA_NAME>> TO <<USER_PRINCIPLE>>;
      GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::"dbo" TO "dbMaintanenceUser";
```